# unable to authenticate your SAML github

Tags: git, github, single-sign-on

I am getting below error when trying access github, could anyone help please.
( Unable to authenticate your SAML session (invalid SAML message). Please try again or contact an administrator of your enterprise.)

[SAML github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbMaL.png)

Comment: I suggest you do what it says and contact your administrators

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Microsoft Account for SAML authentication, it can related to your time settings on your local machine.

I have experienced the same issue as you, and for some reason, my time settings are sometime reset to UTC+0 whereas they should be set normally to UTC+6.

In windows `Date And Time` settings, I have unchecked and checked again `set time automatically` to get the correct time and timezone, which fixed the issue with Github SAML authentication.

See similar issue faced by a Linux User in [Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/office-365-sign-in-redirect-on-firefox/d52a5350-5cfe-4442-9cb5-11c97a5cca52).